# How to make an object spawn when a condition is met on game maker

Tags: game-maker

I have been making a game on game maker and i wanted an object to spawn in my room when a certain amount of score is reached. i have tried this by doing:

```
if global.score >= 10
{
    instance_create(obj_flag);
}
```

but when i go to run it it says " there is a wrong number of arguments for function instance_create"

It would be much appreciated if some one could help me.
Thankyou

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know game-maker, but a quick google search shows that `instance_create()` takes three arguments, hence the error about the *wrong number of arguments*:

http://gamedesign.wikidot.com/gamemaker:instance-create

```
id = instance_create( x, y, obj );

 id = returned instance id
  x = x location to create object
  y = y location to create object
obj = name of object to create an instance of

instance_create() creates an instance of an object at 
the specified x/y coordinates. It also returns the instance 
id of the instance created, which can be put into a variable
and used to manipulate the instance.
```

So it looks like the API is requiring you to specify where to create it.